# Web form shows resource cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC4 project where I added a couple of web forms to its root directory which have crystal report as its content.

They work fine locally but when I uploaded the project to the web server all the Web Forms show `the resource cannot be found`.

I tried adding this line in the route config to make the route engine ignore any page with .aspx bit it didn't help.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?" });
```

Comment: Check in the properties of the web form that the Build Action is set to Content

Comment: it is set to content, is there anything in IIS that would cause this issue ?